# failed to join domain using Microsoft Custom script extension

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, virtual-machine, devops

I'm trying to add a host to the domain with a Powershell script using Microsoft Custom Script extension of azure virtual machine. The script fails with the error below when i try to deploy it using Microsoft extension. It's succeed when I run it manually on the host.

Has anyone seen this issue before?
Below is my script

```
$domainName = "domain.com"
$serviceAccountName = "accountname"
$serviceAccountPassword = "password"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $serviceAccountPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$serviceAccountCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($serviceAccountName, $securePassword)

Add-Computer -DomainName $domainName -Credential $serviceAccountCredential -Restart
```

i am facing an error unable to update the password

Error
message: Unable to update the password. The value provided as the

> current
> password is incorrect.

`

Answer (score 0):

> Error message: Unable to update the password. The value provided as the current password is incorrect.

I have followed this [MS Document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1316) as reference to join the **VM** to join the domain using extensions.

To resolve the issue, add the domain name to your username.

> Ex: "domain\username"

Here is the updated script.

```
$domainName = "sample.com"
$serviceAccountName = "sample\venkat"
$serviceAccountPassword = "password"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $serviceAccountPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$serviceAccountCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($serviceAccountName, $securePassword)
Add-Computer -DomainName $domainName -Credential $serviceAccountCredential -Restart
```

**Extension status:**

[image]

Successfully joined the domain.

[image]